# adding custom controller directory in zend framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

so in the index.php I did

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front = $front->addControllerDirectory('/path/to/directory');
```

and then I placed one of my controller files in that /path/to/directory

but then Zend complains that it couldn't find that controller...

What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you remeber to namespace your controllers correctly, you added a new controller directory you did not reset the default controller directory. So you have to make sure the namespacing is correct and you may have to update the autoloader.   Application_Path_To_MyController()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from zend manual :

> Note: If you use addControllerDirectory() without a module name, it
>   will set the directory for the default module -- overwriting it if it
>   already exists.

so specify the module name where your custom controllers are if it's not the default module :

```
$front->addControllerDirectory('/path/to/directory', 'moduleName');
```

however you can also add it in application.ini file :

application.ini :

```
; resources frontController
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory[] = APPLICATION_PATH "/path/to/directory1"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory[] = APPLICATION_PATH "/path/to/directory2"
```